# Cant find copy function in shutil module

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I am using Python version 2.7.10, I imported the shutil module for use, but it doesnt run the copy function when its supposed to, so when I run the dir command to see all the functions, I can only find the **builtins**, **doc**, **file**, **name**, **package** and **shutil**

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The command is `dir(shutil)`, and `copy` certainly is there. Please post your code so we can see where your error is.

Comment: Your script named `shutil.py` or there's a directory or another file in your script directory named `shutil` or `shutil.py`. That is, rename it then all things will be fine :)

Comment: Kevin, you were right on your comment, one of my scripts in the working directory was labelled that, but why is that undetectable when I have a file named shutil.py? Thanks much for the expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try accessing python in the command line like this

```
python

import shutil
shutil.copy
<function copy at 0x105393aa0>
```

if the output is the "function copy at 0x105393aa0" there is no error then there should be a copy function